# UBUNTU is blocking some 443 port traffic when should not

Tags: ufw

I have UFW instaled and configured like that.

```
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere

80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**And i'm getting this log in /var/log/syslog**

> Jan 14 16:06:03 mymachine kernel: [ 2108.808970] **[UFW BLOCK]** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=52:3f:93:17:6d:bb:40:a6:77:34:67:f0:08:00 SRC=107.201.193.137 **DST=125.124.235.79** LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=16935 DF **PROTO=TCP** SPT=57973 **DPT=443** WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0

Comment: Can you please post all your rules ? Order matters. 443 allow is the same as the 2 rules accepting tcp and udp both

Comment: Anywhere                   ALLOW       !.!.!.!  /// My own ip, hidden here for security options
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: i add /tcp and /udp specific, after read a post recommendig that

Comment: port 443 (https) uses only tcp , so the udp rule does not add anything, or if anything just makes your rule list longer. Please edit your question and add the output of : `sudo ufw show added` . If the output is long, use pastebin https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit

Comment: Also, hiding your ip does not really add much if anything to security these days. But if you really *must* hide it, edit your question  to remove it from the output of your logs. I bolded it for you, so you can spot it in the future, but you can xxxxx it out if you must. I also showed you where 443 is using TCP.

Comment: sudo ufw show added

ufw allow from xxxxxxxxxxxx
ufw allow 80
ufw allow 443
ufw allow 443/tcp
ufw allow 443/udp

Comment: The rules are working fine in general, but some packets to DPT=443 are been blocked, but not all traffic to this port.

Comment: The packets must have been blocked by some default rule in ufw than. Hard to say . You can list and review all the rules with `sudo iptables -L`